# Javascript documentation is vague in VS Code, is there a plugin to show more?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, code-documentation

Excuse my naïvety, but I find Flutter/Dart documentation very intuitive and easy to use in VS Code. Same goes for Android Studio when I was using it. Now using VS Code for javascript and Parse Cloud code there is almost zero documentation. Am I doing something wrong or is there a plugin for javascript to get more data? Same goes for Atom which I was using initially and gave absolutely zero documentation for javascript even with some autocomplete plugins.

This makes it extremely difficult to learn the APIs. Is there a plugin for javascript that I'm unaware of?

Flutter package documentation on hover:
[image]

Flutter autocomplete (also shows more data about method if available):
[image]

Javascript & Parse Cloud Code documentation- ZERO DATA:
[image]

Comment: it can only show you what the developers of the package provide.  It can always show you a function signature but if you get more advanced stuff, depends on if they provided types for their code.

Comment: VSCode understands JSDoc comments. You don't need any plugin. You just need to comment your modules properly. Some libraries have jsdoc comments so you get it for free if you use them

Comment: So it's an issue of package lacking documentation then?

Comment: Flutter is also strongly typed. So there is no way around providing the types from the package developer side. JavaScript doesn't enforce this, so it really depends on if they felt like it.

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense now. Thanks